# Do 1D random walk probability distributions generally converge to gaussian functions?

Tags: probability, random-walk

Suppose I have a 1D random walk, where the step size is not a constant but a random variable that is a function of a set of independent continuous random variables $x^i$ with given probability distributions $\phi^i(x^i)$. Each step the computation of the step size is done independently of all previous steps.

Is it correct to conclude that the probability distribution of the distance from the origin converges to gaussian, regardless of the forms of $\phi^i$ or the step size function?

Comment: See, for instance, the Lindeberg or the Liapunov criteria for some insight into the conditions that need to hold for Gaussian asymptotics.  When, in your situation, the limiting distribution (appropriately standardized) is Gaussian, then it is said to enjoy a Central Limit Theorem (or that the CLT holds).  For simple counterexamples imagine a step size that doubles each time.  Thus, if you do have such a situation to analyze, you will make more progress towards an answer here by providing the details.

Comment: I cannot add much specific details, this problem is not taken from any book or course material but simply something I stumbled upon while working on a loosely related problem. But thank you for the comment, I will search the criteria